# Three.js material disable interpolation

Tags: three.js

I have a 64x64 pixel texture that consists of white and transparent pixels and should be used as an overlay. The problem is that the texture is stretched and the rendering has to be pixel-perfect. But when the texture is rendered the edges between white and transparent pixels are interpolated but they have to be sharp edges. How do I disable interpolation for this specific material?

Material definition:

```
this._groundOverlayMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    transparent: true
});
```

The map is created separately using a canvas and then set using:

```
this._groundOverlayMaterial.map = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(overlayCtx.canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
this._groundOverlayMaterial.needsUpdate = true;
```

Info: The mesh is a simple plane with no subdivisions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to set the texture's [Magnification & Minification filters](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=canvas#api/en/constants/Textures) to "Nearest Neighbor", which removes interpolation between pixels, and instead "snaps" to the closest pixel, similar to `Math.round()` to the nearest full integer.

```js
// Create texture from canvas
const texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(overlayCtx.canvas);
texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;

// Use that texture in your material
this._groundOverlayMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    transparent: true,
    map: texture,
});
```

You might only need it when magnifying the texture, not sure if you need it for minifying.